# How to mock typeorm connection

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, typeorm

In integration tests I am using the following snippets to create connection

```
import {Connection, createConnection} from 'typeorm';
// @ts-ignore
import options from './../../../ormconfig.js';

export function connectDb() {
  let con: Connection;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    con = await createConnection(options);
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await con.close();
  });

}
```

I am trying to unit test a class which calls **typeorm repository** in one of its method and without call that helper function **connectDb()** above I get the following error which is expected of course.

> ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found.

My question is how can I mock connection. I have tried the following without any success

```
import typeorm, {createConnection} from 'typeorm';
// @ts-ignore
import options from "./../../../ormconfig.js";

const mockedTypeorm = typeorm as jest.Mocked<typeof typeorm>;

jest.mock('typeorm');

 beforeEach(() => {
    //mockedTypeorm.createConnection.mockImplementation(() => createConnection(options)); //Failed
    mockedTypeorm.createConnection = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => typeorm.Connection);

    MethodRepository.prototype.changeMethod = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return true;
    });
  });
```

Running tests with that kind of mocking gives this error

> TypeError: decorator is not a function

**Note**: if I call connectDb() in tests everything works fine. But I don't want to do that since it takes too much time as some data are inserted into db before running any test.
Some codes have been omitted for simplicity. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Is decorator a method on a typeorm Connection?

Comment: @Nux have you solved this problem? if so, could you share your solution?

Comment: @Orhaan I haven't solved it! But read this question it may give you right direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61693597/how-to-mock-typeorms-getcustomrepository

Answer (score 1):

After a bunch of research and experiment I've ended up with this solution. I hope it works for someone else who experienced the same issue...

- it does not need any DB connection
- testing service layer content, not the DB layer itself
- test can cover all the case I need to test without hassle, I just need to provide the right output to related typeorm methods.

This is the method I want to test

```
@Injectable()
export class TemplatesService {
  constructor(private readonly templatesRepository: TemplatesRepository) {}

  async list(filter: ListTemplatesReqDTO) {
    const qb = this.templatesRepository.createQueryBuilder("tl");
    const { searchQuery, ...otherFilters } = filter;
    if (filter.languages) {
      qb.where("tl.language IN (:...languages)");
    }
    if (filter.templateTypes) {
      qb.where("tl.templateType IN (:...templateTypes)");
    }
    if (searchQuery) {
      qb.where("tl.name LIKE :searchQuery", { searchQuery: `%${searchQuery}%` });
    }
    if (filter.skip) {
      qb.skip(filter.skip);
    }
    if (filter.take) {
      qb.take(filter.take);
    }
    if (filter.sort) {
      qb.orderBy(filter.sort, filter.order === "ASC" ? "ASC" : "DESC");
    }
    return qb.setParameters(otherFilters).getManyAndCount();
  }

...
}
```

This is the test:

```
import { SinonStub, createSandbox, restore, stub } from "sinon";
import * as typeorm from "typeorm";

describe("TemplatesService", () => {
  let service: TemplatesService;
  let repo: TemplatesRepository;

  const sandbox = createSandbox();
  const connectionStub = sandbox.createStubInstance(typeorm.Connection);
  const templatesRepoStub = sandbox.createStubInstance(TemplatesRepository);
  const queryBuilderStub = sandbox.createStubInstance(typeorm.SelectQueryBuilder);
  stub(typeorm, "createConnection").resolves((connectionStub as unknown) as typeorm.Connection);
  connectionStub.getCustomRepository
    .withArgs(TemplatesRepository)
    .returns((templatesRepoStub as unknown) as TemplatesRepository);

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const builder: TestingModuleBuilder = Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
          type: "postgres",
          database: "test",
          entities: [Template],
          synchronize: true,
          dropSchema: true
        })
      ],
      providers: [ApiGuard, TemplatesService, TemplatesRepository],
      controllers: []
    });
    const module = await builder.compile();

    service = module.get<TemplatesService>(TemplatesService);
    repo = module.get<TemplatesRepository>(TemplatesRepository);
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
    // do something
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore();
    restore();
  });

  it("Service should be defined", () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });


  describe("list", () => {
    let fakeCreateQueryBuilder;

    it("should return records", async () => {
      stub(queryBuilderStub, "skip" as any).returnsThis();
      stub(queryBuilderStub, "take" as any).returnsThis();
      stub(queryBuilderStub, "sort" as any).returnsThis();
      stub(queryBuilderStub, "setParameters" as any).returnsThis();
      stub(queryBuilderStub, "getManyAndCount" as any).resolves([
        templatesRepoMocksListSuccess,
        templatesRepoMocksListSuccess.length
      ]);
      fakeCreateQueryBuilder = stub(repo, "createQueryBuilder" as any).returns(queryBuilderStub);
      const [items, totalCount] = await service.list({});

      expect(fakeCreateQueryBuilder.calledOnce).toBe(true);
      expect(fakeCreateQueryBuilder.calledOnce).toBe(true);
      expect(items.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
      expect(totalCount).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    });
  });
});
```

cheers!