# How to mock AxiosInstance with jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, axios

I want to unit test a class which use axios to send post request to another server but I keep getting the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined

Here are my codes

```
//PostController.ts
const axios = require('axios').default;

export class PostController {
  async sendPostRequest(): Promise<boolean> {
    //type AxiosInstance
    const instance = axios.create({
      baseURL: 'http://example.com',
      timeout: 60 * 3 * 1000, //milliseconds. 3 minutes. 
      headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'secret-key'}
    });

    const {status} = await instance.post('/submitUsername', {username: 'nux'});

    return status === 200;
  }
}
```

And this is how my test look like:

```
//PostController.test.ts
import {PostController} from './ProviderController';
import axios from 'axios';

const mockedAxios = axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>;

jest.mock('axios');

describe('PostController', () => {
  it('should send post request and return 200', async () => {
    const controller = new PostController();
    const response = {status: 200};

    mockedAxios.post.mockResolvedValue(response);
    const result = await controller.sendPostRequest();

    expect(mockedAxios.post).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(result).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

What could be wrong here? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to mock out `axios.create` too.

Comment: My answer here might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60413756/7470360

Comment: @AJarofClay thanks my problem is solved.

Comment: @AJarofClay I am very new to mocking things, could you please take a look at this question too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60813752/how-to-mock-typeorm-connection

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mock inner axios.create()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51393952/mock-inner-axios-create)

Comment: @AJarofClay .. Yes