# How to mock typeORM's getCustomRepository

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, typeorm

I want to unit-test a class which getCustomRepository in it's constructor but I just can't figure an easy way to mock it. Here is my class code

```
import {getCustomRepository} from 'typeorm';

export class Controller {
  private repository: UserRepository;

  constructor() {
    this.repository = getCustomRepository(UserRepository); //I want to mock this.
  }

  async init() {
    return this.repository.findUser(1);
  }
}
```

and here are tests

```
describe('User Tests', () => {
  it('should return user', async () => {
    //Fake user to be resolved.
    const user = new User();
    user.id = 2;

    //I want to mock  getCustomRepository(UserRepository); here
    //getCustomRepository = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(UserRepository); HERE HOW???

    //Mocking find user
    UserRepository.prototype.findUser = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(user);

    const controller = new Controller();
    const result = await controller.init();
    expect(result).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Note: Mocking repository methods works well but I really want to mock getCustomRepository so as It may reduce time which is wasted trying to connect to database.

This is how getCustomRepository in typeORM looks like

```
export declare function getCustomRepository<T>(customRepository: ObjectType<T>, connectionName?: string): T;
```

UserRepository.ts

```
@EntityRepository(User)
export class UserRepository extends Repository<User> {
  public async findUser(id: number) {
    return 'real user';
  }
}
```

User.ts

```
@Entity('users')
export class User{
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({type: 'varchar', length: 100})
  name: string;
}
```

So question is how do I mock it? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: In your `Controller` class, how does the `getCustomRepository` get imported? Can you add that part to your question?

Comment: @mgarcia I have edited. It is imported like this `import {getCustomRepository} from 'typeorm';`

Comment: @mgarcia any suggestion?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [jest.mock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) to mock `typeorm` module, `getCustomRepository` function and its returned value.

E.g.

`controller.ts`:

```js
import { getCustomRepository } from 'typeorm';
import { UserRepository } from './userRepo';

export class Controller {
  private repository: UserRepository;

  constructor() {
    this.repository = getCustomRepository(UserRepository);
  }

  async init() {
    return this.repository.findUser(1);
  }
}
```

`userRepo.ts`:

```js
export class UserRepository {
  public async findUser(id: number) {
    return 'real user';
  }
}
```

`controller.test.ts`:

```js
import { Controller } from './controller';
import { getCustomRepository } from 'typeorm';
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';
import { UserRepository } from './userRepo';

jest.mock('typeorm', () => ({ getCustomRepository: jest.fn() }));

describe('61693597', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const userRepo = { findUser: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce('fake user') };
    mocked(getCustomRepository).mockReturnValueOnce(userRepo);
    const controller = new Controller();
    const actual = await controller.init();
    expect(actual).toBe('fake user');
    expect(getCustomRepository).toBeCalledWith(UserRepository);
    expect(userRepo.findUser).toBeCalledWith(1);
  });
});
```

unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61693597/controller.test.ts (13.53s)
  61693597
    ✓ should pass (9ms)

---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File           | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files      |   92.31 |      100 |      80 |   90.91 |                   
 controller.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 userRepo.ts   |      80 |      100 |      50 |      75 | 3                 
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        15.596s
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/tree/master/stackoverflow/61693597

Comment: Thanks for response. Your codes works absolutely fine. But I got some more problem I forgot to mention earlier. Typeorm's repository  has decorators so as entity.

Comment: with this solution I get error of this kind `Test suite failed to run
    TypeError: typeorm_1.PrimaryGeneratedColumn is not a function` and I believe decorators are now the problem

Comment: the mocked() function did not work for me, and I had to include sinon as a dependency in order to make it work. sharing my answer in a bit.

Comment: @malvadao `mocked` helper function only provides TS typings, not a concrete implementation. You need to use `jest.mock()`, `jest.fn()` to mock module/functions

Answer (score 2):

As previously mentioned in a comment, I have tried replicating @slideshowp2's answer. The `mocked()` util from ts-jest was returning 'mockResolvedValueOnce' as undefined.

To solve it, I had to break it down into some steps:

1. include **sinon** as a dependency to perform more in-depth mocking
2. (**very important**) create a wrapper for the `getCustomRepository` function

Without the wrapper, it is virtually impossible to mock the return since the property is *readonly*. It should be enough to do something like:

```
c: Connection;

public async getCustomRepository<T>(type: ObjectType<T>): Promise<T> {
    if (!this.c || !this.c.isConnected) {
      this.c = await this.getConnection();
    }
    return await this.c.getCustomRepository(type);
  }
```

After doing so, I have managed to mock the `getCustomRepository` function like so:

```
describe('Unit tests', () => {
let sandbox: sinon.SinonSandbox;
let useCase: FindNodeUseCase;
let repositoryStub: sinon.SinonStub;
let nodeTreeRepo: NodeTreeRepository;

beforeEach(() => {
  sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
  useCase = new FindNodeUseCase();

  const mockNode = new NodeTree();
  mockNode.idNode = 1;
  mockNode.level = 1;
  nodeTreeRepo = new NodeTreeRepository()
  nodeTreeRepo.findOne = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockNode)
  nodeTreeRepo.findByIdAndLanguage = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(
    [
      [{ idNode: 1, level: 2, names: [{ idNode: 1, nodeName:"Sales" }] }],
      1
    ]
  );
  repositoryStub = sandbox.stub(useCase.databaseManager, 'getCustomRepository').resolves(nodeTreeRepo)
})

afterEach(() => {
  sandbox.restore();
})
```

Comment: `mocked` helper function only provides TS typings, not concrete implementation

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same issue a bit later as it seems. Here is for future visitors a version that is currently working:

my `spec.ts` file

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';

import { GraphDataService } from './graph-data.service';

jest.mock('typeorm', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('typeorm'),
  getCustomRepository: jest.fn(),
}));

describe('GraphDataService', () => {
  let service: GraphDataService;

  beforeAll(() =>
    jest.mock('typeorm', () => ({
      ...jest.requireActual('typeorm'),
      getCustomRepository: jest.fn(),
    })),
  );

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [GraphDataService, { provide: 'ObjectValidator', useValue: {} }],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<GraphDataService>(GraphDataService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Works with nestjs@7.6.1 and typeorm@0.2.26